# Is there a function in R to get all the same rows between two data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, they have the same number of columns but not the same number of rows, and I'd like to know what are the rows in common between those two data frames.

[image]

So imagine i have two data frame exactly like this but one got more rows than the other one.
And I expect as a result to have a data frame that contains only the rows in common between the two data frames.

I tried the merge(data.frame1, data.frame2, by = "Name2") in terms of rows it gives me the result i'm expecting but i got the columns twice, because i only want the 7 columns that i got initially and the rows in common.
Also all the 7 value on the rows should match not just one

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Probably a simple `merge()` would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you mean row names, when you say rows in common, you can simply do this:

```
index <- which(row.names(df1) %in% row.names(df2))

df1_common_rows <- df1[index,]
```

Comment: Thank you ! it worked but i needed to modify your solution a bit :
b <- which(dataframe1$value2 %in% dataframe2$value2)
a <- dataframe1[b,]